# Front end for MS SQL with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, forms, visual-studio

I've happily created an MSSQL database which, from my point of view, works well and gives me what I want.  If the boss wants info from it, he could ask me.  It would be better if it had a front end.

I've looked around and seen recommendations for Visual Studio/Lightswitch and ironically am a little in the dark....

1) Presumably VS 2013 and Lightswitch aren't the same thing, or is the latter part of the former?
2) I've easily connected my SQL to a trial version of VS 2013, but cannot make what I would call 'forms' in any other app (such as Access) which can call and update data.
3) Before I venture on and spend further time in this avenue, does anybody know if VS2013 would be able to build the app I need on a desktop to access SQL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can still use Access. Search online for "access as a front end for sql server". Lightswitch is like Access on steroids but has a steeper learning curve. C#/VB.NET require you to do everything yourself (including data access). Your choice depends mostly on your current level of technical competence and timescale restrictions

Comment: You can create forms over data using ASP.NET, Windows Forms Data Binding to DataSets, Entity Framework etc. But it requires more code. Though these video's are a bit old and I'm sure there is a tutorial out there somewhere that showcases the latest EntityFramework and WPF features, this could be a start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb798022.aspx#formsoverdata